# APIGEE returns 200 despite the target server returning 400

Tags: postman, apigee

We are seeing a case where, on the target server, we are specifically setting the response status code to 400, we also see in the trace that APIGEE shows 400, but when checking in postman we see 200 as response status code.

[image]

[image]

In above image, postman is showing status code as 200 'OK' when APIGEE responds as 400 'Bad Request'. 
 1. If APIGEE responds 401 status code postman is showing correct status
    code.
 2. If APIGEE responds 400 or 422 status code postman is showing invalid status code as 200 'OK'.

Are we doing any thing wrong, or should we add any other specfic rule to correct this?

I am using on-prem APIGEE. Version 4.15.04.00 Please guide me.

Comment: you have a list of filter and script on your workflow. Can you do a list or are you sure you don't have one that do something (cache ? rules like if 400 the 200 ...)

Comment: you are using multiple `Assign Message` policies, could you paste the content for these, maybe you are setting a response in these. Ideally, Assign messages are used to prepare a payload for a Service Call or a Raise Fault etc: Try raising faults when a few conditions are not met rather than returning an object through assign message.

Comment: This issue is fixed currently, this is because we had data power as firewall protection for on premesis APIGEE that is converting error response 400 to 200. And we modified Assign message policies as<Header name="exact_status_code">400</Header>
 <Header name="exact_status_message">Bad Request</Header>. thanks for comments